# CTE returning error

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I wrote a CTE to remove non numeric values from a data set, then get a count of numeric values within a range.

```
WITH    dtr
      AS ( SELECT   resultlevel r
           FROM     dbo.Result
           WHERE    DrugID = 'AMP'
                    AND ISNUMERIC(ResultLevel) = 1
                    AND AuditStamp > '1/1/2016'
                    AND DeleteFlag = 0
         )
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    dtr
WHERE   CONVERT(INT, r) BETWEEN 50 AND 75
```

This returns an error in SMS

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'PND            ' to data type int.
```

This error is completely possible without the 'dtr' query in the CTE.

When I rewrite this, instead of a CTR, but a TEMP table, it works.

```
SELECT  resultlevel r
INTO    #d
FROM    dbo.Result
WHERE   DrugID = 'AMP'
        AND ISNUMERIC(ResultLevel) = 1
        AND AuditStamp > '1/1/2016'
        AND DeleteFlag = 0

SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    #d
WHERE   CONVERT(INT, r) BETWEEN 50 AND 75
```

So my questions is why?? I have always thought a CTE was like creating a TEMP table.

**TEST DATA**

```
if object_id('tempdb..#temp') is not null drop table #temp

create table #temp (result char(5)) 
insert into #temp (result) values 
('1'),('A'),('>2'),('PEN ') ,('@3'),('-2'),('-33') 


;with isnum AS ( 
SELECT result 
FROM #temp 
WHERE ISNUMERIC(result) = 1)

--Selecting from the CTE yields 1, -2, and -33 all of which can be converted to INT
--Running the query with the where clause causes the conversion error
SELECT 
    result, 
    ISNUMERIC(result)
FROM isnum
--WHERE CONVERT(INT,result) > 1
```

Comment: Not exactly - a `CTE` isn't a temp *table*.  A more accurate description is that it is a temporary *view*.  And will behave as such.

Comment: @DMason - receive the same result, but I updated the date so they are the same.

Comment: change the cte select to `trim(resultlevel) r`?

Comment: You should get the same error in the temp if the data is the same.... and `select ISNUMERIC('PND            ')` doesn't equal 1 so I feel like there has to be more here... is there some code you are leaving out? That value shouldn't be int he CTE result set.

Comment: If you run `Select isnumeric('PND            ') as result;` what is the value of result?

Comment: @scsimon.... Select isnumeric('PND ') = 0.  I have thought the same & the SQL is exactly what I posted above... The temp table returns a number & the CTE an error....I even copied back to SMS & reran.

Comment: Try select * from dtr where isnumeric(r) = 0 and see what's all returned compared to the same code on #d

Comment: @scsimon - an empty record set... no error...

Comment: @larryr well that means the code in the CTE is working correctly, as expected.... and thus the error shouldn't be throwing on the conversion. With what we have right now your problem isn't reproducible it doesn't seem.

Comment: @scsimon - If can be duplicated here 

create table #temp (result char(5))

insert into #temp (result) values ('1')
insert into #temp (result) values ('A')
insert into #temp (result) values ('>2')
insert into #temp (result) values ('PEN ')
insert into #temp (result) values ('@3')
insert into #temp (result) values ('-2')
go
WITH    calc
          AS ( SELECT   result
               FROM     #temp
               WHERE    ISNUMERIC(result) = 1
             )
    SELECT  CAST(result AS INT)
    FROM    calc
    WHERE CONVERT(INT,result) > 1

DROP TABLE #temp

Comment: If you run the CTE query adding in the hint OPTION ( FORCE ORDER) at the end, do you still get the error?

Comment: VERY interesting @larryr and i stand corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `SQL Server` there is [Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx), which determines when the objects defined in one step are made available to the clauses in subsequent steps:

1. FROM
2. ON
3. JOIN
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY
6. WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
7. HAVING
8. SELECT
9. DISTINCT
10. ORDER BY
11. TOP

This is how your query is going to be proccesed and your query looks perfectly fine. But sometimes, the `SQL Server` decides not to follow this order in order to optimize your query.

In your case, the `SQL Server` might be simplyfing/transforming your query into another and performing the `convert` function, before applying the `where isnumeric` filtering.

If we made your query a little more complex (but still giving the same results), the `SQL Server` is executing the code correctly this time:

```
;with isnum AS ( 
    SELECT result
    FROM #temp 
    WHERE ISNUMERIC(result) = 1
    GROUP BY result
    HAVING MAX(result) = result
)
SELECT 
    result, 
    ISNUMERIC(result)
FROM isnum
WHERE CONVERT(INT,result) > 1;
```

In your case (and this is what I am doing in such situations when different types are stored in one column), you can simply use [TRY_CONVERT](https://www.google.bg/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=msdn%20try_convert%20sql) function:

```
;with isnum AS ( 
SELECT result 
FROM #temp 
WHERE ISNUMERIC(result) = 1)

SELECT 
    result, 
    ISNUMERIC(result)
FROM isnum
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(INT, result) > 1
```