# Error converting data type varchar to numeric in sql when value is compared in where clause

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion, numeric

I have a dataset of decimal values that are stored as varchar.
I need to return all of the values that are less than 8.0.
This is my query:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT PatientEncounterID, CAST(value as numeric(3,1)) As Value
from Observation 
where Term = 'HGBA1C' AND isnumeric(value) = 1
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE Value < 8.0
```

When I run this query I get the error:

> converting data type varchar to numeric

When I run the query without the where clause the values range from 5.0 to 16.9.
The other column is just an identity field.
The `Value` field is converted to a number in the CTE query.
Why can the where clause error?

**UPDATE**
The total rows is 228.  There should be 144 returned but only 39 are returned.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41109677/6167855

Comment: Be careful using ISNUMERIC to isolate values that are actually numbers. Things "1e8", '¢', '$.' will all evaluate to 1 with isnumeric but will throw an exception with your predicate. To me the biggest issue you have is storing what you determine as decimal in a varchar column. You obviously have some values that are not actually decimals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a result of the query optimizer deciding to perform the query as a single query. It combined all of your `WHERE` conditions and chooses to perform the `Value < 8.0` check before the `ISNUMERIC` check. To get around this, you need to filter all numeric values first and put it in a temporary table:

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable
SELECT *
FROM Observation
WHERE
    Term = 'HBGAIC'
    AND ISNUMERIC(Value) = 1;

SELECT *
FROM  #TempTable
WHERE CAST(Value AS NUMERIC(3, 1)) < 8.0;
```

Comment: That worked!  Wow...would have not thought of that.  I thought that is the whole point of a CTE.  Thanks!