# SQL Invalid column name - computed condition in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following query:

```
SELECT ImgHeight, ImgWidth,
 IIF(ImgHeight > ImgWidth, ImgHeight, ImgWidth) as imgMaxSize
 FROM Images
WHERE imgMaxSize > 100
```

But I am getting message:

> Invalid column name 'imgMaxSize'.

I could duplicate the condition as following, but it doesn't seem to be effective to compute the maximum twice.

```
SELECT Img1Height,
 Img1Width,
 IIF(Img1Height > Img1Width, Img1Height, Img1Width) as imgMaxSize
 From Realty
where IIF(Img1Height > Img1Width, Img1Height, Img1Width) > 100
```

What is the recommended approach here?

Comment: But putting it in the `WHERE` (like the second example) is exactly what you should do. The `WHERE` clause is ran before the `SELECT` clause, and hence at that point, the SQL-OS does not know what is imgMaxSize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can use `outer apply` for this:

```
SELECT i.ImgHeight, i.ImgWidth, v.imgMaxSize
FROM Images i OUTER APPLY
     (VALUES(CASE WHEN i.ImgHeight > i.ImgWidth THEN i.ImgHeight ELSE i.ImgWidth END)
     ) v(imgMaxSize)
WHERE v.imgMaxSize > 100;
```

Of course, CTEs and subqueries also solve the problem; I just happen like this use of lateral joins.

Or:

```
SELECT i.ImgHeight, i.ImgWidth,
       (CASE WHEN i.ImgHeight > i.ImgWidth THEN i.ImgHeight ELSE i.ImgWidth END) as imgMaxSize
FROM Images i 
WHERE i.ImgHeight > 100 or i.ImgWidth > 100;
```

I should add that I'm also quite biased toward ANSI standard syntax unless there is a good reason to use something else.  Hence, `outer apply` has a good reason.  `IIF()` instead of `CASE` is not a good reason.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
select * from (
    SELECT ImgHeight, ImgWidth,
        IIF(ImgHeight > ImgWidth, ImgHeight, ImgWidth) as imgMaxSize
    FROM Images
    ) as i
WHERE imgMaxSize > 100
```

Or:

```
with cte as (
    SELECT ImgHeight, ImgWidth,
        IIF(ImgHeight > ImgWidth, ImgHeight, ImgWidth) as imgMaxSize
    FROM Images
);

select * from cte
WHERE imgMaxSize > 100
```

Comment: If I understand it good, in case of CTE entire source table is loaded in memory because there is not where condition. So the subquery is more effective in case of large tables. Am I right?

Comment: @qub1n You can never know about this activity. SQL-Server only supposed to do what you want, but it choose how to do it on its own. Check this question as an example of it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41109677/cte-returning-error